# Google Drive API returning unexpected results on resumable upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, google-drive-api, drive

I'm trying to follow [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable) for Google Drive API interaction, specifically to perform a resumable upload. I want to be able to upload larger 50MB+ image files, as well as modify the uploaded file's description in Google Drive to contain some user-entered text.

I'm capable of performing the login/authentication without issue. I run a jQuery AJAX call to the OAuth2 `/token` endpoint, and it provides me with a valid `access_token`, which I can then use to make direct calls to the API.

I then make an AJAX call to the `/files?uploadType=resumable` endpoint, as per the documentation, setting the HTTP headers to include the `access_token`, setting the `Content-Type`, and so on. I also include the metadata, which in this case is the intended name of the newly-uploaded image file.

However, the response I get from the API is confusing. It gives me a `status` of 200, which according to the documentation is the expected response, but the returned `statusText` reads `"parsererror"`.

According to the Google documentation, I should be receiving back a `location` string of a resumable session URI, which I can then use as the endpoint for a PUT request, wherein I include the file's data in the request body. However, in the object I receive back, I'm not seeing any `location` string or URI as expected.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here's the jQuery AJAX call that's returning the confusing object:

```
function fileUpload() {

        var metadata = { "name" : "New Image" };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                request.setRequestHeader("X-Upload-Content-Type", new_mime_type);
                request.setRequestHeader("X-Upload-Content-Length", new_file_size);          
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(metadata),
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Resumable upload POST call success. Returned data:");
                console.log(data);

                // Do a second $.ajax POST call here...?

            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log("Resumable upload POST call error. Returned data:");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: For example, is this information useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/ResumableUploadForGoogleDrive_js

Comment: @Tanaike Outstanding, this is precisely what I was looking for! And, I was able to edit the new file's upload name and description. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tanaike So this script is uploading directly to my personal drive. However, I'm trying to upload files to a Shared Drive, of which I am not the administrator. How can the code be modified to allow this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the library cannot be used for the shared drive. I would like to also implement it. But I cannot test it. So I cannot achieve it. I deeply apologize for this situation.